# How to get 2 min(year) and count(title) from tables by MySQL?

Tags: mysql

[image]

How can I select count(title) and two minimum year 1995,1996, and starName from table?

What is the query about this?

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group by to group records by starName and then use aggregate functions to find the result,

```
SELECT starName, count(title), min(year) from TABLE GROUP BY starName;
```

Comment: It's good to encourage users to demonstrate what they've tried first, before spoon-feeding the answers to what are very simple questions.